# Monitoring K8s Pods in case of outage

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, logging

K8s has self-healing builtin features, if a pod crash then it will be replaced with the new pod but its log is gone. So what is the best way to monitor K8s pods in case of outage?

Answer (score 1):

For health monitoring, I would recommend the [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator). If you are looking for application logs, you should consider a logging stack such as elasticsearch-fluentd-kibana. I personally would recommend the [kube-fluentd-operator](https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator). Additionally, if you would like to see the kubernetes events I find [eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter) quite useful which can also be wired into your logging infrastructure.